# Print channel from Slack

Tags: printing, slack

When using Slack, how can I print all of the messages that were said in a channel for my records?

Comment: I guess this is a way of doing https://levels.io/slack-export-to-html/

Comment: It looks like it would but I had problems running it.  I was in a hurry so I just did it manually.  Revelant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1205/

Answer (score 4):

In order to store and print messages from a channel you use the export feature in the client or develop a script that uses the web API.

The export feature works fine, however there are a few constrains:

- can only be done by admins or owners
- only works for public channels
- the format is JSON (one file per channel, each message is one element
  in a JSON array)

See here for further information on the [Slack help pages](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204897248).

I also found a Slack App called [Export](http://export.fountstudio.com/) that allows to export the full content of a channel for storage and later printing. This app supports exporting for any channel the user as access to including private channels. Messages can e.g. be exported in HTML for printing with the browser. The app works fine, but the output quality is a bit rough and seams to lack images and conversation of Slack link syntax to HTML.

Another approach is to develop your own script. You only need to read all messages of a channel directly via web API (with `conversations.history`][3](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history)) and then process it further (e.g. convert to output file for printing). That will work for both public and private channels, but obviously requires a bit of coding.

Comment: Looking on the 3K views there seams to be a lot of interest for such a feature. So it might be worthwhile creating a Slack app for it.....

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe late, recently i have write a chrome extension "slack printer" to export the slack messages into html, also support pdf/png/json, event markdown.
Try it in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/slack-printer/pmoidapkjjlhcdbdjojaekbdlkdjjoab
using this tools, no need as admin role, hopefully it can make your life easier.

Comment: This did not get all threaded messages for me.